# Flexbox substitui as GRID?

Tags: css3, grid, flexbox

Andei dando uma olhada nas propriedades flex, e percebi que elas fazem a mesma coisa que as grid ou estou errado? Se sim qual a diferença delas ? Quando devo usar uma ou outra ?

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse posto do Tutorialzine, explica um pouco sobre o sistema de Grid do Bootstrap (o que muita gente usa) e sobre o sistema de Flexbox. http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2016/11/boostrap-4-regular-vs-flex-grid/?1-basic-grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Conceitos**

**Flexbox**:

> Faz parte da especificação do CSS3 que promete organizar elementos na
>   página previsivelmente quando o layout precisa ser visualizado em
>   diversos tamanhos de tela e em diversos dispositivos. O Flexbox ajuda
>   a organizar esses elementos sem a ajuda do `float` e também nos ajudam a
>   sanar problemas de Box Model que normalmente acontecem quando
>   acrescentamos, `padding`, `margin` e `border` além da largura do elemento.

(Fonte: [Flexbox, CSS](https://eduardojoaquimsilva.wordpress.com/tag/css/))

**Grid**:

> É uma estrutura que permite o conteúdo ser empilhado verticalmente e
>   horizontalmente de uma forma consistente e facilmente gerenciável.
>   Além disso, o código de um sistema de grid é um "*project-agnostic*",
>   dando-lhe um elevado grau de portabilidade, de modo que, possa ser
>   adotado em novos projetos.

(Fonte: [Grid,Tableless](http://tableless.com.br/entendendo-sistemas-de-grid-css-do-zero/))

### **Diferença**

- **Flexbox** é essencialmente para colocar os itens em uma única dimensão - em uma linha ou uma coluna.
- **Grid** é para o layout de itens em duas dimensões - linhas e colunas.

### **Quando usar?**

As duas podem ser usadas em conjunto para ter um código melhor. O `Grid` pode ser utilizado nas áreas externas (cabeçalho, corpo, menu, rodapé) e o `FlexBox` para componentes.

Referências:

- [Flexbox](http://tableless.com.br/flexbox-organizando-seu-layout/)
- [Grid](http://tableless.com.br/entendendo-sistemas-de-grid-css-do-zero/)
- [Flexbox e Grids](http://blog.tecmedia.com.br/flexbox-e-grid-layout-css3/)